# How can I compare different versions of an unitemporal document in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I have multiple versions of a unitemporal document stored in a unitemporal collection in a MarkLogic database .

The system start date is taken from an element within the document and the system end date is stored in the metadata.

I want to know how I check the differences and compare the changes in the multiple versions of the same file.

Answer (score 1):

You do not state if the documents are JSON or XML or text etc.

Tooling to find the actual differences will depend on your document type.

However, to get the documents in order for a given document can be done as follows:

The URI is also a collection.
For the "latest" version of the document, query using a `cts:collection-query` on the URI.

That will isolate all of the versions of the document.

To order them in a search, you would likely have set up a field for the temporal axis and add a range index on that. That range index can be used in  a search for the order-by.

Comment: Thanks , I am using xml documents. And I am using unitemporal document where I am taking the system start date from the file within and the system end date in the metadata. Can you tell me how I can search or compare different versions of the file . Do we have any MarkLogic documentation particularly for this use case ?